# Jitsi Jirecon issue while starting the recording component

Tags: javascript, java, recording, jitsi

I know that jirecon is out of scope [ support ] from jitsi-meet but the new solution Jibri is not applicable to my appliance of jitsi-meet and recording is very much needed in my case ,

so here is my issue when I start a conference I notice that the record button appear then disapper and I followed the logs and here is the stacktrace that I found on Jirecon :

```
INFO: Recording task of MUC paltel@conference.avchat2.paltel.ps started.
Aug 17, 2017 10:46:30 AM org.jitsi.util.LoggerImpl log
WARNING: Unknown DTLS handshake message type: -58
Aug 17, 2017 10:46:30 AM org.jitsi.util.LoggerImpl log
WARNING: Unknown DTLS handshake message type: 41
Aug 17, 2017 10:46:30 AM org.jitsi.util.LoggerImpl log
WARNING: Unknown DTLS handshake message type: 52
Aug 17, 2017 10:46:30 AM org.jitsi.util.LoggerImpl log
WARNING: Unknown DTLS handshake message type: -64
Aug 17, 2017 10:46:30 AM org.jitsi.util.LoggerImpl log
INFO: jnopenssl successfully loaded
Aug 17, 2017 10:46:32 AM org.ice4j.ice.Agent setState
INFO: ICE state changed from Completed to Terminated
Aug 17, 2017 10:50:38 AM org.jitsi.util.LoggerImpl log
SEVERE: No SctpSocket found for ptr: 139746425060000
SEVERE: Failed to decode a DTLS record!
java.io.IOException: org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DatagramTransportImpl is closed!
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DatagramTransportImpl.assertNotClosed(DatagramTransportImpl.java:124)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DatagramTransportImpl.receive(DatagramTransportImpl.java:375)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSRecordLayer.receiveRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSRecordLayer.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSTransport.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.reverseTransformDtls(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:927)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.transformDtls(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:1427)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.transform(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:1373)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.reverseTransform(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:857)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.TransformEngineChain$PacketTransformerChain.reverseTransform(TransformEngineChain.java:380)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.TransformInputStream.createRawPacket(TransformInputStream.java:84)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.RTPConnectorInputStream.runInReceiveThread(RTPConnectorInputStream.java:810)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.RTPConnectorInputStream.access$000(RTPConnectorInputStream.java:41)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.RTPConnectorInputStream$3.run(RTPConnectorInputStream.java:607)

Aug 17, 2017 11:20:32 AM org.jitsi.util.LoggerImpl log
SEVERE: Failed to decode a DTLS record!
java.io.IOException: org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DatagramTransportImpl is closed!
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DatagramTransportImpl.assertNotClosed(DatagramTransportImpl.java:124)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DatagramTransportImpl.receive(DatagramTransportImpl.java:375)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSRecordLayer.receiveRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSRecordLayer.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSTransport.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.reverseTransformDtls(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:927)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.transformDtls(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:1427)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.transform(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:1373)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.reverseTransform(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:857)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.TransformEngineChain$PacketTransformerChain.reverseTransform(TransformEngineChain.java:380)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.TransformInputStream.createRawPacket(TransformInputStream.java:84)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.RTPConnectorInputStream.runInReceiveThread(RTPConnectorInputStream.java:810)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.RTPConnectorInputStream.access$000(RTPConnectorInputStream.java:41)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.RTPConnectorInputStream$3.run(RTPConnectorInputStream.java:607)

Aug 17, 2017 11:20:32 AM org.jitsi.util.LoggerImpl log
SEVERE: Failed to decode a DTLS record!
java.io.IOException: org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DatagramTransportImpl is closed!
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DatagramTransportImpl.assertNotClosed(DatagramTransportImpl.java:124)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DatagramTransportImpl.receive(DatagramTransportImpl.java:375)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSRecordLayer.receiveRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSRecordLayer.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSTransport.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.reverseTransformDtls(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:927)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.transformDtls(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:1427)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.transform(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:1373)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.reverseTransform(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:857)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.TransformEngineChain$PacketTransformerChain.reverseTransform(TransformEngineChain.java:380)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.TransformInputStream.createRawPacket(TransformInputStream.java:84)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.RTPConnectorInputStream.runInReceiveThread(RTPConnectorInputStream.java:810)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.RTPConnectorInputStream.access$000(RTPConnectorInputStream.java:41)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.RTPConnectorInputStream$3.run(RTPConnectorInputStream.java:607)

Aug 17, 2017 11:20:32 AM org.jitsi.util.LoggerImpl log
SEVERE: Failed to decode a DTLS record!
java.io.IOException: org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DatagramTransportImpl is closed!
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DatagramTransportImpl.assertNotClosed(DatagramTransportImpl.java:124)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DatagramTransportImpl.receive(DatagramTransportImpl.java:375)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSRecordLayer.receiveRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSRecordLayer.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.DTLSTransport.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.reverseTransformDtls(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:927)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.transformDtls(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:1427)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.transform(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:1373)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.DtlsPacketTransformer.reverseTransform(DtlsPacketTransformer.java:857)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.TransformEngineChain$PacketTransformerChain.reverseTransform(TransformEngineChain.java:380)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.TransformInputStream.createRawPacket(TransformInputStream.java:84)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.RTPConnectorInputStream.runInReceiveThread(RTPConnectorInputStream.java:810)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.RTPConnectorInputStream.access$000(RTPConnectorInputStream.java:41)
    at org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.RTPConnectorInputStream$3.run(RTPConnectorInputStream.java:607)
```

Google Logs:

```
[modules/xmpp/JingleSessionPC.js] <i>:  Processing addRemoteStream
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/JingleSessionPC.js] <i>:  ICE connection state:  failed
index.js:146 Halt: There are no SSRC groups in the remote description.
Logger.js:125 [modules/RTC/TraceablePeerConnection.js] <r._remoteTrackAdded>:  TPC[1,p2p:false] remote track added: 85edf678-def9-499b-8a90-13af57be026a audio
Logger.js:125 [modules/RTC/TraceablePeerConnection.js] <r._remoteTrackAdded>:  TPC[1,p2p:false] associated ssrc jirecon 1887751681
Logger.js:125 [JitsiConference.js] <r.onRemoteTrackAdded>:  No participant found for id: jirecon
r @ Logger.js:125
Logger.js:125 [modules/RTC/TraceablePeerConnection.js] <r._remoteTrackAdded>:  TPC[1,p2p:false] remote track added: 85edf678-def9-499b-8a90-13af57be026a video
Logger.js:125 [modules/RTC/TraceablePeerConnection.js] <r._remoteTrackAdded>:  TPC[1,p2p:false] associated ssrc jirecon 1793628094
Logger.js:125 [JitsiConference.js] <r.onRemoteTrackAdded>:  No participant found for id: jirecon
r @ Logger.js:125
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/SdpConsistency.js] <e.value>:  TPC[1,p2p:false] sdp-consistency replacing new ssrc262679192 with cached 262679192
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/JingleSessionPC.js] <>:  addRemoteStream - OK, SDPs:  r r
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/JingleSessionPC.js] <t.value>:  removal not necessary
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/JingleSessionPC.js] <t.value>:  addition not necessary
Logger.js:125 [modules/statistics/RTPStatsCollector.js] <a.processAudioLevelReport>:  1887751681 not enough data
r @ Logger.js:125
Logger.js:125 [modules/statistics/RTPStatsCollector.js] <a.processAudioLevelReport>:  1793628094 not enough data
r @ Logger.js:125
Logger.js:125 [modules/xmpp/ChatRoom.js] <t.value>:  Ignore focus: paltel@conference.avchat2.paltel.ps/jirecon, real JID: focus@auth.avchat2.paltel.ps/Smack
Logger.js:125 [modules/connectivity/ParticipantConnectionStatus.js] <e.value>:  No participant for id: jirecon
r @ Logger.js:125
strophe.js:4843 XHR finished loading: POST "https://avchat2.paltel.ps/http-bind?room=paltel".
l @ strophe.js:4843
_processRequest @ strophe.js:4855
_throttledRequestHandler @ strophe.js:5013
_onIdle @ strophe.js:4633
_onIdle @ strophe.js:3718
setTimeout (async)
_send @ strophe.js:4972
send @ strophe.js:2653
sendIQ @ strophe.js:2757
value @ strophe.ping.js:67
(anonymous) @ strophe.ping.js:107
strophe.js:4843 XHR finished loading: POST "https://avchat2.paltel.ps/http-bind?room=paltel".
```

Comment: Could you explain why jibri is not applicable?
Jirecon currently has no support, so I do not recommend that you implement it because you can find many problems.

Comment: @AlfredoGt jibri ,do record for only one session as I understood from the solution it spawn a google window and start the record

Comment: Check this out: [link](https://github.com/jitsi/jibri/pull/39)
you should keep in mind that the recording generates a high CPU consumption, if you need to record more than one session at a time, you must have a good server.

Comment: @AlfredoGt , but I couldn't it make jabri work either , it connects but no recording was done